# Print the Assigned Value of Each Variable using For Each loop in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I Have assigned Values for Each Variable of External Parameters but I'm unable to Call the Assigned Value through Loop.

The Code Which I'm using now is there for reference.

Thanks in Advance...

```
Module Module1
    Public Int_Parameters() As String = {"Int_D1", _
                             "Int_D2", _
                             "Int_D3", _
                             "Int_D4"}

    Public Ext_Parameters() As Integer= {"Ext_D1", _
                             "Ext_D2", _
                             "Ext_D3", _
                             "Ext_D4"}
    Sub Assigning_Values()
         Ext_D1 = 25
         Ext_D2 = Ext_D1 + 25
         Ext_D3 = Ext_D2 + 25
         Ext_D4 = Ext_D3 + 25
    End Sub

    Sub Loop()
         For Each Int_Parameter As String in Int_Parameters
             For Each Ext_Parameter As String in Ext_Parameters

             Int_Parameter = Ext_Parameter 'Ext_Parameter Value is 0 but i need the Assigned Values instead of 0
             Next
         Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: first you should have your `In` keyword in the For statement: `For Each Int_Parameter As String In Int_Parameters` and same for `For Each Ext_Parameter As String In Ext_Parameters`

Comment: Oops Actually It was their in Original Code this Code is a kind of Demo Code made only to Clear the Issue of Getting Assigned Values...

Comment: Well to help you correctly we need the correct code if words are missing we cant help you

Comment: Corrected the Mistake in Code...

Comment: Well first problem I see is your` Assigning Values Sub` and The `Ext_Parameters` your defining it as `Integer` but your giving it a string value. `"Ext_D1"` Could you try to explain in clear way what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry it was Integer Only. I'm a Mechanical Guy Learning and Doing Program Simultaneously so Please bare my mistake this time nd i'll try not to happen again. Int_Parameter is a Variable with the Same Name of my Autodesk Inventor Part Parameter. Ext_Parameter is a Variable i'm using it for Some Calcualtions in VB. Based on the user Input the Calculated Value will be send to Autodesk Inventor.

Comment: so why not do this? Public Ext_Parameters() As Integer= {25, 50, 75, 100}

Comment: These are not predefined values it has to be calculated based on the user inputs so how can i use Public Ext_Parameters() As Integer= {25, 50, 75, 100}

Comment: well how do you get the user input

Comment: User Inputs are Via Text box in Forms

Comment: Please try to be precice when you answer... does the user fill in all the values of Ext_Parameters of just the first one and then increment by 25?

Comment: @Mederic I got the answer and I'm Sry for not so Clear. The Values are not increment of 25 it was some formula instead of that i kept it randomly.

Comment: Josha your ideas are way to broad and unorganised to help you sorry you need to define exactly what you want to do and how you will do it before you actually code it: you can just have a list of integer based from formula: on button click list.add(convert.toint32(textbox32.text)) and then run your formula to add other values like: list.add(list.items(0) + 25 etc

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

Public Int_Parameters() As String = {"Int_D1", _
                         "Int_D2", _
                         "Int_D3", _
                         "Int_D4"}

Public Ext_D1, Ext_D2, Ext_D3, Ext_D4 As Integer

Public List1 As New ArrayList

Sub Assigning_Values()

 Ext_D1 = 25
 Ext_D2 = Ext_D1 + 25
 Ext_D3 = Ext_D2 + 25
 Ext_D4 = Ext_D3 + 25

Dim Ext_Parameters() As Integer= {"Ext_D1", _
                         "Ext_D2", _
                         "Ext_D3", _
                         "Ext_D4"}

For Each Ext_Parameter As Integer in Ext_Parameters
        List1.Add(Ext_Parameter)
Next

End Sub

Sub Loop()

 For Each Int_Parameter As String in Int_Parameters
     For Each Ext_Parameter As Integer in Ext_Parameters

     Int_Parameter = Ext_Parameter 

     Next
 Next

End Sub

End Module
```